# How to effectively optimize queries in Presto?

Tags: presto, clickhouse, greenplum

Testing Presto technology and looking for really useful ways to improve Presto query performance. While unsuccessfully, the methods described in the documentation do not bring any result at all.
All the followers are inflating the technology, supposedly it is able to perform federated queries, at high speed and on big data. But as it comes down to it, these high-profile narratives burst and Presto becomes an ordinary product that is applicable closer to Hadoop and then not on really large data, but on relatively small ones, which can most likely improve Hive, but nothing more, and why is it needed then if do you have Spark?
How else to explain that in GreenPlum I execute a query to the source for facts containing hundreds of billions of rows, and I significantly limit it with conditions and add several joins to reduce the volume in the WITH construct and then only count.
And if I send such a request to GreenPlum, I get a response in less than 1 minute.
When run in Presto, the query is not executed, because for some reason it unloads all the facts in their entirety.
And he takes all 3 tables that can be calculated inside the source, and only then he thinks that he can calculate it. And neither dynamic filters, nor distribution methods, nor anything else help.
A very limited tool. Those. for another 12 years they haven’t taught him really useful skills and there’s no point in using it, or is there something I don’t know and have already found a way to make it a little smarter?

Tried everything available on the net. Apart from the inconvenience of using Presto, there are really few advantages. It showed itself well on join operations in ClickHouse, but this is not enough. We need effective ways to interact with ClickHouse and GreenPlum. Presto is also very picky about data types, especially numeric and UID.